# Let $\{c_n\}$ be a sequence and $\{c_{n_i}\}$ any subsequence. Show if $\sum c_n$ is absolutely convergent, then ...

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

... $\sum c_{n_i}$ is absolutely convergent.

The best I can show is $\sum c_{n_i}$ converges. This is because $\sum c_n$ being absolutely convergent implies it is convergent. If we define a sequence of partial sums of $c_n$, we can construct a subsequence of this sequence that corresponds to $\sum c_{n_i}$, thereby showing the latter expression converges. But, this does not imply absolute convergence.

Answer (score 3):

Let $C = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |c_n| < \infty$. Then $\sum_{i=1}^k |c_{n_i}| \leq C$ for any $k$ so the partial sum sequence for $\sum |c_{n_i}|$ is monotone increasing and bounded above.

However, unless I'm mistaken, your proof that $\sum c_{n_i}$ converges doesn't quite work. The problem is that you can't extract the partial sum sequences of $c_{n_i}$ as a subsequence of the partial sum sequence for $c_n$ in general. To see this, note that the partial sum sequences for $c_{n_i}$ could, for example, look like $$c_2 + c_4 + c_6 + \dots + c_{2k}$$ whilst any subsequence of the partial sum sequence for $c_n$ will involve terms of the form $c_{2n+1}$ (and in particular $c_1$).

Of course, convergence of $\sum c_{n_i}$ does follow from the absolute convergence shown above.

Comment: (+1); indeed, if you take the alternating harmonic series then the sequence $c_2 + ... + c_{2k}$ is divergent, so *absolute* convergence is really critical here and just identifying subsequences is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\displaystyle\sum_{i}|c_{n_{i}}|\leq\sum_{n}|c_{n}|<\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{n}$ is absolutely convergent
then the sequence $(\sum_{k=1}^{n} |c_{k}|)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of partial sums is convergent. This is equivalent to the convergence of the tail sequence
$(\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} |c_{k}|)_{n=1}^{\infty}$
 to zero.
That is, given any positive number $\epsilon$, there exits $N_{\epsilon}$ such that 
$$|\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} |c_{k}| |<\epsilon$$ for all $n >N_{\epsilon}.$

So, if  $(c_{n_{k}})_{k\geq 1}$ is a subsequence of $(c_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ then

$$|\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} |c_{n_{k}}| |<\epsilon$$ for all $n >N_{\epsilon}$
because, by the definition of a subsequence, $n_{n}\geq n$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Hence the sequnce $(\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} |c_{n_{k}}|)_{n=1}^{\infty}$
converges to 0, and equivalently $(\sum_{k=1}^{n} |c_{n_{k}}|)_{n=1}^{\infty}$
is convergent.

Comment: This doesn't work. Notice that the sum corresponding to the subsequence can miss values appearing in the sum for the sequence itself. For example, let $c_{2n} = 0$ and $c_{2n+1} = 2^{-n}$. Then the $s$ in your answer is $2$ but it is clear that $\sum_{k=1}^n |c_{2k}| = 0$ which is never within $\epsilon$ of $2$ for small $\epsilon$.

Comment: @ nobody. I corrected my answer. Please, modify the vote!